# A GENERAL inequality for a bi-modal hypergeometric distribution

Tags: mathematical-statistics, hypergeometric-distribution

Say $X$ has a hypergeometric distribution with parameters $m$, $n$ and $k$, with $k\leq n<\frac12m$.

I know that $X$ has a dual mode if and only if $d=\frac{(k+1)(n+1)}{m+2}$ is integer. In that case $P(X=d)=P(X=d-1)$ equals the maximum probability.

See [my previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/458289/506). I got a great answer proving $P(X=d+1) > P(X=d-2)$. That got me wondering: can we make a more general statement? More specifically (for natural $c \leq d-2$):

$P(X=d+c) > P(X=d-1-c)$

This is [true](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/458956/506) for $c = 1$, but also in many cases when $c \geq 2$. I have not found any counterexamples yet. Can this be proven? Or where to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn [the answer from the other question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/458956/164061) into an inductive proof for this question*.

$$\tfrac{P(X=d+c+1)}{P(X=d+c)}-\tfrac{P(X=d-c-2)}{P(X=d-c-1)} = \tfrac{(k-d-c)(n-d-c)}{(d+1+c) (m-k-n+d+1+c)} -\tfrac{ (d-c-1) (m-k-n+d-c-1)}{(k-d+c+2)(n-d+c+2)} \\= \tfrac{(k-d-c)(n-d-c)(k-d+c+2)(n-d+c+2)-(d-c-1) (m-k-n+d-c-1)(d+1+c) (m-k-n+d+1+c)}{(d+1+c) (m-k-n+d+1+c)(k-d+c+2)(n-d+c+2)}$$

again the denominator is positive, and we only need to show that the numerator is positive.

We can do the same steps, substituting $d=(k+1)(n+1)/(m+2)$ [gives for the numerator](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28k-d-c%29%28n-d-c%29%28k-d%2Bc%2B2%29%28n-d%2Bc%2B2%29-%28d-c-1%29+%28m-k-n%2Bd-c-1%29%28d%2B1%2Bc%29+%28m-k-n%2Bd%2B1%2Bc%29%29+with+d+%3D+%28k%2B1%29%28n%2B1%29%2F%28m%2B2%29):

$$(c+1)^2(m-2k)(m-2n)$$

which is positive when both $k< \frac{1}{2}m$ and $n < \frac{1}{2}m$.

---

Some other interesting points

- For $c = 0$ you get the previous answer.
- For $c=-1$ you get $\frac{P(X=d)}{P(X=d-1)}-\frac{P(X=d-1)}{P(X=d)} = 0$, which is true by the assumption $P(X=d) = P(X=d-1)$.
- Also for $n=\frac{1}{2}m$ you get that the term $(m-2n)$ equals zero and you get the symmetry $P(X=d+c) = P(X=d-c-1)$

---

**If $\tfrac{P(X=d+c+1)}{P(X=d+c)}-\tfrac{P(X=d-c-2)}{P(X=d-c-1)}> 0$ and $$P(X=d+c) \geq P(X=d-1-c)$$ then $P(X=d+(c+1)) > P(X=d-1-(c+1))$*

Comment: @MicheldeRuiter I wanted to make some elegant argument that is more based on some reasoning with properties or links between different distributions or with certain known principles in probability/mathematical statistics. But I could not do better than simply copying the other answer and extending it a bit. ..... This question is very much mathematics. I wonder what the application is that you have in mind?

Comment: I'm researching properties of the hypergeometric distribution.